# Angular 5 view not displaying updated property value after initial change

Tags: angular, components, observable, subject

My view isn't showing the updated property value of a local property, bound model property, nor a value from observable. Logging from console shows all the values are updated.

This is a multi-step form and works great with exception of this annoying issue:

The first time I click on booth, clickBooth(e) is fired as expected and the view updates with the value.

I click on another booth to 'add' it, all the same code fires, but the view doesn't reflect the new updated value of `selectedboothlabels` or `newbookingform.booths`

Move on in the form, (using a continue button that fires a 'changeStep' method), then go back to this particular section of the form, the correct values of `selectedboothlabels` and `newbookingform.booths` are displayed in the view.

Tried so many things. I think I'm running in circles now. This is the latest of many versions of code:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';    

@Injectable()
export class SelectedBoothService {

  public boothlist = new Subject<string[]>();

  setBoothList(value: string[]) {
    this.boothlist.next(value); 
  }
  getBoothList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.boothlist.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Relevant from View (very, very simplified):

```
{{selectedboothlabels}}<br>
{{newbookingform.booths}}
```

NOTE: I tried binding `newbookingform.booths` (which is part of the BookingForm ngModel on a form) to a simple text input. However the value is NOT updated through the input, so don't believe this does anything.

Relevant Code from Component:

```
import { SelectedBoothService } from '../../services/selectedbooths.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { BookingForm } from '../../models/booking.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'reserve-booth',
    templateUrl: './reserve-booth.component.html'
})
export class ReserveBoothComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedboothlabels: string[] = [];
    boothlistsubscription: Subscription;
    newbookingform: BookingForm = new BookingForm();

    constructor(
        private _changedetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private _selectedboothService: SelectedBoothService) {

            this.boothlistsubscription = 
              this._selectedboothService.getBoothList().subscribe(list => {
                     console.log("Subscribing to the boothlist: " + list); //shows most recent values perfectly
                     this.selectedboothlabels = list;
                     this._changedetector.markForCheck(); //no affect...
             });
    }

     //fired from an custom component. Works great. 
     clickBooth(e) {
          let boothindex = -1;
          let targetid = e.currentTarget.id;
           //check our list of selectedbooths.
           if (this.selectedboothlabels != undefined) {
               boothindex = this.selectedboothlabels.indexOf(targetid);                  
           }
           if (boothindex == -1) {
              //add to our list
              this.selectedboothlabels.push(targetid);
              boothindex = this.selectedboothlabels.indexOf(targetid);                               
              this.newbookingform.booths = this.selectedboothlabels;
              this._selectedboothService.setBoothList(this.selectedboothlabels); 
           } else {
             //already here. Remove it.
             this.selectedboothlabels.splice(boothindex, 1);                
             this.newbookingform.booths = this.selectedboothlabels;                
             this._selectedboothService.setBoothList(this.selectedboothlabels);

             boothindex = this.selectedboothlabels.indexOf(targetid);                 
          }

          this._changedetector.detectChanges(); //seems to have no affect 
       }
     }
```

Comment: Could you put your code on stackblitz.com?

Comment: @EHeine `this._selectedboothService.getBoothList().subscribe()` in the `constructor` will be subscribed only once, you need to do this again after mutating your list (at the end of `clickbooth`)

Comment: import OnInit to the component with the method ngOnInit(). Remove the getBoothList() code from the constructor and place it inside the ngOnInit() method.

Comment: @dickrichie I had tried this previously. I tried again but results haven't changed..

Comment: @cyberpirate92 Just tried this, no change. I'm confused though as I understood that once a component is subscribed to an observable, it should 'watch' for updates to that value...or am I completely misunderstanding subscribing to observables.(very possible)

Comment: @tika  I will try. What I posted is an extremely simplified portion of one component of a massive booking system.

Comment: @EHeine It's better to declare a public `Observable`/`BehaviorSubject` in your service and subscribe to it directly instead of using a method to return a subscription.

Comment: Why convert subject to observable? Why not use a strongly typed observable declared inside the class like: import {Booth} from './booth'; //booth class. Then declare like: booth: Booth[];. And then use Booth[] as your return observable inside the get like: getBoothList: Observable<Booth[]>:{};